# Spring unmodifiable View-/Display- Object

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, modelattribute, modelandview

I want to display data which i am getting from my db in a view. As far as i know, in case i set my objects in the model defined as @ModelAtttibute, the user will be able to manipulate the data. For example: if my model has the attribute "firstname", the user will be able to manipulate the value by accessing the attribute over a get parameter(...?firstname=blabla)

In this case the model attribute is used for displaying data and not for processing user input and accodingly i dont want the user to overwrite values.

Has anyone any solutions/pattern for solving this problem?

Comment: Post your code, explain what it's supposed to do, and what the problem is. I don't even understand why you would use ModelAttribute to get data from the DB and put it in the model.

Comment: Which part didn't you understand? The point is that the user/client is able to modify the model independently how i fill my model.

Comment: I don't understand why you refuse to post your code when asking for help.

Comment: Because it's a general question and it has nothing to do with my code